# SEO & WordPress: Changing category links manually

Tags: wordpress, seo

I'm not too sure about SEO on WordPress as I read somewhere (I think) that Google penalises category pages for duplication and was hoping someone could tell me whether or not it's a good idea to cut out the links to the category pages all together?

My permalink structure for my main navigation does not link to the category pages. I have created a page specifically for tutorials like so:

**myurl.com/tutorials/tutorial-type**

and then on the pages there is an if-statement that gets posts from a specified category for that page.

so **myurl.com/tutorials/tutorial-type** will get only posts in the **tutorial-type** category.

What i'm planning is instead of using the:

```
<?php the_category(', '); ?>
```

in the typical **Posted in: Tutorials** format under the title of the post to a quick function that will direct someone to the main page for that category. like so:

```
function changeCategoryToPage() {

    if (in_category( 'tutorial-type' )) { ?>
       <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tutorials/tutorial-type">Tutorial Type</a>
    <?php }

}
```

I would appreciate your feedback and wisdom :)

Comment: So basically you recreate the content of an category archive inside a page... 

Google does not care about the template behind the html displayed, just about the content. If you list your posts the same way as in the category archive, you have exactly the same risk of duplicate content - or not - as on the archive + unnecessary code and redirects. 

You can work on category.php to add specific content, like the description, but, basically the risk of duplicate content is more linked to your content organization than anything else.

Comment: yes so I can have the desired url structure - it currently adds /category/ to the url

Comment: google doesnt penalise category pages for duplication.

Comment: You can use plugins like single category, i.e. correct the rewriting only instead of duplicating a core process